# Ktor server on android device, where is the path of " static ", want to show index.html

Tags: android, server, ktor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z76Rn.png)
"Ktor can run on Android with HTTP and
can serve static content（？）, such as index.html.
Does index.html work in Ktor on Android?
If so, which package should I use in my project?"

but i can not find static web in Browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your file structure, the following configuration should work for you:

```
static("/test") {
    resources()
    defaultResource("index.html")
}
```

For example, the server would respond with the content of the `app/src/main/resources/index.html` file to the `GET /test` request and with the `app/src/main/resources/image/image.png` file to the `GET /test/image/image.png` request.

Comment: i found a way the same as you.  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10070520/229683928-801cf2a9-9427-4746-b5f2-54af2470149a.png